# Model interpretation lmer?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, modeling, fixed-effects-model

I have 139 subjects (ID), with measurements taken at two time points (Time1, Time2), at 148 brain regions, a dependent measure called volume, and a covariate called thickness.

Each subject has 148 brain regions with volume and thickness measured twice

I am trying to find out if there is a difference in volume between timepoint 1 and timepoint 2 while controlling for thickness. I want to know **which brain regions show this difference.** I need help setting up the model. Specifically the timepoint part is throwing me off...

I am using R. and trying to figure out a model with linear mixed models with (1|ID) as random factor, fixed factors regions, thickness.

What I have is:

delta-volume <- volume_time 2 - volume_time1

```
 Mod1   lmer(delta-volume ~ delta.thickness + volume_time_1 + regions + (1|ID))
```

Mod2 lmer(delta-volume ~ delta.thickness + regions + (1|ID)

```
 Mod3 lmer(delta-volume ~ delta.thickness + (1|ID/regions)
```

from model 1

1) is there a difference in volume from from timepoint 1 to timepoint 2?

2) Which regions show a significant difference?

The way I interpreted is for question 1) is that the fixed effect intercept is the value of the depedent variable when the IV variables are defaults so, in my case, the intercept was positive, I interpreted it as there was a decrease in volume. Is this correct?

2) stuck on how to see which regions....I get estimates for them but what do those mean?

Also would very much appreciate an explanation about how the models differ... 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Are the 148 regions together spanning the entire brain? In other words, are these regions the only ones you could have included in your study or did you leave some brain regions out of your study?

You do have a lot of regions but let's say you included all regions of interest in your study (leaving none out). Then you will find it easier to formulate your model like this:

```
Mod1   lmer(volume ~ time + region + thickness + (1|ID)
```

or

```
Mod2   lmer(volume ~ time*region + thickness + (1|ID)
```

Model 1 assumes that the (true) change in volume from time 1 to time 2 (controlling for thickness) for a given subject is the same across all brain regions. It also assumes that change is consistent (i.e., the same) across subjects.

Model 2 assumes that the (true) change in volume from time 1 to time 2 (controlling for thickness) is different across regions within the same subject, but the region-specific change in volume from time 1 to time 2 is assumed to be consistent across subjects.

For both models, you can replace (1|ID) with (1 + time|ID) if you believe the changes in volume are inconsistent (i.e., different) across subjects.

Both Model 1 and Model 2 assume that each individual is measured twice for each region, so your data would look like this:

```
ID    time region volume etc.
1     1     1     ?   
1     2     1     ?
.
.
.
139   1     138   ?
139   2     138   ?
```

The coefficient of time in model 1 will represent the true change in volume between time 1 and time 2 for a typical subject given a region and thickness (assuming time was coded as a factor whose reference/baseline level is time 1). Since this coefficient is the same for all regions, you would test whether or not it is equal to 0 and also report a confidence interval for it.

For Model2, you would have to set up contrasts to test whether the true change in volume between time 1 and time 2 is different from 0 for each of your regions of interest. With so many regions, you will need to control for multiplicity of your tests.

You should determine first which of Model 1 or Model 2 is more appropriate for your data.

If the 138 regions are not exhausting all of the brain regions one could possibly consider, things are a bit more complicated. I'll let others on this forum address that scenario.

Comment: Did you delete the comment which said those were ALL the regions included?

Comment: Your Mod3 would make sense if the regions included in your study were not exhuasting the entire brain and were selected to be representative of a larger set of regions.

Comment: 1. those are all the brain regions included   2. if I understand correctly you are suggesting to get rid of delta.volume and use volume ? 3. Model 2 makes more sense physiologically 4. "would have to set up contrasts to test whether the true change in volume between time 1 and time 2 is different from 0 for each of your regions of interest." - How could I do that? 5. I have time coded as a factor timepoint 1 = 1 timepoint 2 = 2. Is that what you meant?

Comment: What's tricky in your set up is that, if you analyze the data the way I suggested, you may need to worry about correlation across time and/or space in the values of the response variable 'volume'. The suggested model 1, for example, only allows for correlation over time between values of the response (and assumes that it is the same) for the same subject but ignores correlation over space. It is conceivable that the volumes of regions that are 'close' in space to each other are more similar than the values that are far apart.

Comment: You can analyze the difference in volume the way you suggested in your Mod1 since this will still leave you with multiple response variable values for each subject - one response value per region. But you may need to worry about the potential spatial correlation of these values for the same subject. Right now, you are assumping the response values for the same subject are equally correlated, whether they come from regions that are 'close' or 'far' from each other.

Comment: do you mean `Mod1   lmer(delta-volume ~ delta.thickness + volume_time_1 + regions + (1|ID))` ?

Comment: Yes! In your Mod1, the response is the difference in volume. The regions is a factor with 148 levels.  If you reformulate the model as lmer(delta-volume ~ -1 + regions + delta.thickness + volume_time_1 + (1|ID)), then R will explicitly estimate for you the mean difference in volume between timepoint 1 and timepoint2 for a "typical" subject separately for each region, controlling for difference in thickness and volume at timepoint 1.

Comment: The -1 removes the intercept and no longer compares each region against the reference region.

Comment: So what you want is to test whether the true mean difference in value for each region is 0 (null hypothesis) vs. different from 0 (alternative hypothesis) for each of the 148 regions and then flag those regions where the null hypothesis can be rejected.

Comment: But because you have 148 tests to perform, you will need to correct for multiplicity. You can get the unadjusted p-values produced by lmer and adjust them with p.adjust, for example: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/p.adjust.html.  Maybe use the "fdr" adjustment since you have so many tests?

Comment: To accommodate spatial correlation, you would need to define the "centre" of your region and determine its x and y coordinates somehow. See https://ms.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/eeid/lme.pdf for an example. This is complicated, so first ignore the spatial correlation and then look to see whether doing so creates any issues.

Comment: Thank you very much! "The -1 removes the intercept and no longer compares each region against the reference region"  Does this mean that it automatically compares it against 0?

Comment: No - it doesn't do any between-region comparison when you exclude the fixed intercept. It just estimates the mean change in volume for each region, all else being equal.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean between-region. I meant the p-value refers to testing whether the true mean difference in value for each region is 0 vs different than 0 fo each of the 148 regions.

Comment: Yes, if you exclude the fixed effect intercept from the model, R will post 148 p-values. The first p-value will be associated with the test of zero change vs. non-zero change for the first region, etc.

Comment: If you DO include the fixed effect intercept in your model, R will use 148 - 1 = 147 dummy variables in your model. Let's say that your first region, region #1, is treated as the reference level. Let's also say that regions is coded in your data as a factor with levels 1 (for region # 1), 2, ..., 148. Then you will have the dummy variables regions2, regions3, ..., regions148 included in your model when you include the fixed effect intercept. Each of these helps you compare the true change/difference in volume between timepoints among region k and region 1, where k = 2, ..., 148.

Comment: So if you want to test whether or not the change/difference in volume between timepoints for region #1 is different from 0, you will have to test whether or the model intercept is different from 0. If you want to test whether or not the change/difference in volume between timepoints for region #2 is different from 0, you would have to test whether or not beta0 + beta1 is different from 0, where beta1 is the coefficient of regions2 in your model (where the model includes a fixed effect intercept). And so on...

Comment: Thus, for the model with intercept, you need to test the 'contrasts' beta0, beta0 + beta1, beta0 + beta2, ..., beta0 + beta147, where beta1 is the coeff of regions2, beta2 is the coeff of regions3, ..., beta147 is the coeff of regions148. This notation assumes that the model lists 1 + regions first in the fixed effects portion, followed by everything else.  You can think of the 'contrasts' as weighted linear combinations of all the fixed effects coefficients in your model, with some weights set to zero.

Comment: Thank you for these  very helpful comments! it seems best to exclude the fixed effect intercept from the model, take the p-values for each regions and adjust them.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to do it the other way around too as a double-check, though it will require a bit more coding.

Comment: One final question... volume_timepoint_1 estimate is negative. Does me not including an intercept influence volume_timepoint_1 ? What is the interpretation for the estimate of this variable?

Comment: In essence, you can define your 148 'contrasts' first if you use the model with intercept and then use multcomp to test whether or not each contrast is zero.

Comment: I wonder if a more meaningful response variable in your case would be "percent change in volume at timepoint 2 compared to timepoint 1"? In other words, response = (volume at timepoint 2 - volume at timepoint 1)/(volume at timepoint 1)x100%?

Comment: With your current outcome, change in volume between timepoints, it seems that higher initial volumes are associated with smaller changes within a given region (controlling for thickness)? Remember that you are not accounting for spatial correlation of change in volume within brain regions of the same patients, so not sure whether this could conspire to give you results which are not plausible?

Comment: That is a good suggestion I will look into that (since the changes are very small). How about the overall change in volume (not just regional), can I get this information from the estimate of volume_timepoint_1 (model without the intercept included) ?

Comment: You already can estimate the region-specific change in volume from your model (with or without intercept). Not sure what the best way to get an overall change would be - maybe to sum up the region-specific changes?  You'd have to think about a meaningful way to define overall change.

Comment: How about if I took out regions: lmer(delta-volume ~ delta.thickness + volume_time_1  + (1|ID)). What would the estimate for volume_time_1 indicate?

Comment: I thought about that too, but then you would have even more spatial correlation to worry about!

Comment: just out of curiosity what would the sign of the estimate volume_time_1 indicate in that case?

Comment: Why not, for each subject, compute the total volume across all regions at timepoint 1 (TV1) and timepoint 2 (TV2). Then your outcome variable will be TV = TV2 - TV1. Do the same for thickness to get TH = TH1 - TH2 for the entire brain. With this, each subject will give you a single response - TV - so you can no longer use a random effects model. Instead, use a linear regression model of the form lm(TV ~ TV1 + TH) .

Comment: In this lm() model, the estimate of TV1 would represent the effect of TV1 on the (mean) change in  volume across the entire brain between the two timepoints among subjects with the same change in thickness between the two occasions.

Comment: You're only including volume at time 1 to control for the fact that different subjects can start out with different volumes at time 1. Then, when you look at changes in volume, you will focus on changes among subjects who start out with the same volume. If you ignore region in your model, the coefficient of volume at time 1 tells you how volume at time 1 affects the change regardless of the region where change occurred.

Comment: I don't think ignoring region is the way to go - a better way is to combine volumes across regions at each time point and then use a model like the lm() model I suggested.

Comment: TH should be defined as TH = TH2 - TH1 in my comment above.

Comment: agreed. great suggestion. the estimate for volume at timepoint1 ends up being positive using the suggested lm. does that suggest an increase in volume at timepoint 2?

Comment: and how about the intercept?  Also to double check... positive estimates from the model including the regions indicate a increase in volume at time2 compared to time 1?

Comment: Hmm...I had a look at https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3816382/#!po=13.3929 and am wondering if you would be better off - when you care about each region - to consider each region separately and fit a different model to each region. This would avert the need to worry about spatial correlation, since you are modelling what happens for one region at the time.  Each model would produce a parameter which quantifies the mean change in volume for that region. You would test whether this parameter is 0 and adjust region-specific p-values for multiplicity across regions.

Comment: For example, the model for region 1 could be an lme model with volume of that region as the response (measured at two time points) and time, thickness (also measured at time points) and subject as a random grouping factor. The coefficient of time would represent the mean change in volume between time points that you care about so you would test it to see whether or not it's 0.

Comment: I really like having time in the model as a factor, because its coefficient tracks the change over time in the values of the response.

Comment: Great idea. Would I still include volume at time 1 as a fixed effect ? In the older lm model a positive volume at timepoint 1 estimate means an increase in volume at time 2? Is that correct ?

Comment: If you measure a response variable at two timepoints, T1 and T2, for a number of subjects for the same region, you can model the trajectory of the response variable over time for that region by using an lme model, whose outcome variable would consist of the response values at times T1 and T2 and predictor variable would be Time, namely a factor with levels T1 and T2. You would not include the value of the response at T1 in your model as a covariate as it is already included in your vector of response values.

Comment: In the lme model, you could add other predictors (e.g., thickness) which vary over time or are time-invariant (e.g., gender).

Comment: The coefficient of Time in this model would represent the rate at which the response variable changes over time for the typical subject. If the lme model includes only a random subject effect, that would imply that all other subjects change at the same rate (though their trajectory starts at different levels). If the lme model also includes a random slope, that would imply both a different starting level and a different rate of change in the expected response levels for all other subjects.

Comment: If you are really intersted in the effect of Time on your response variable (which it seems you are) at a specific region, Time should be included in the model as a Predictor and the response variable should be defined as the vector of response values (i.e., volume) at times T1 and T2.

Comment: In an lme model, if you had 3 (or more) time points (which you don't), you could define the vector of responses as containing the response values at T2 and T3 and then use the response at T1 as a covariate in your lme model. With just two timepoints and a single region, you can't do that and still have an lme model.

Comment: Now going back to the lm model for total volume across all brain regions...Let's say it's a simple model if the form lm(TV ~ 1) or, equivalently, TV = beta0. In this intercept-only model, beta0 denotes the mean change in total volume between timepoints T1 and T2. If you expand the model to lm(TV ~ 1 + TV1 + TH), or equivalently, TV = beta0 + beta1*TV1 + beta2*TH, then beta0 denotes the mean change in volume between timepoints for those subjects with TV1 = 0 (nonsensical) and TH = 0 (i.e., no change in thickness).   So the usefulness of beta0 is debatable.

Comment: Better to switch to the lme model both for modeling change in region-specific volume and for modelling change in overall volume across all regions!

Comment: Time as a factor w/ 2 levels;   Region w/ 148 levels;  ID w/ 28 levels;  For region specific model, you mean to isolate each region and fit lme for each region (to avoid spatial dependency)? how can I do that?

Comment: Yes, based on the reference I provided in an earlier comment, you could isolate each region and fit an lme model for each region. The outcome for that model would be the vector of volume values atvT1 and T2 for that region. The model would include Time and Thickness as time-varying predictors. Just fit 148 such models - each to the data from the corresponding region. The models can have a random subject intercept, but possibly random slopes for Time and/or Thickness.

Comment: The optimal model may be different from region to region, though for simplicity you can start with a random intercept model for each region first. Then test significance of Time coefficient In each model. Get the unadjusted p-value from each model and adjust the entire set of 148 p-values for multiplicity.

Comment: You are going to have to set up something like a for loop to cycle through each model fit and extract the p-value of the test of significance of the fixed effect of Time.

Comment: For the overall model, the lme model would look the same as per my last 3 comments, except that you would only have one model to worry about instead of 148 models.

Comment: I was reading through the paper you mentioned and indeed I agree. I am having trouble "specifying" or telling r to only include one region per model. For example, lmer(volume ~ region1 + time + thickness + (1|ID)). How can I set it up to only look at one region?

Comment: First, you don't need region1 in your lmer model - just time and thickness.  See https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/63556_e35cc7e2dfb54a5bb551f3fa4b3ec4ae.html for how to use a subset of data in your lmer modelling. Essentially, the data = option of lmer should be something like data = subset(yourdata, region == "1") if region is coded like a factor with levels 1,..., 148.

Comment: for all regions: **all_regions <- **lmerTest::lmer(volume~ time + thickness + (1+thickness + time|ID), data = DATA))** To specify that subjects can vary in their starting volume (random intercept), can vary in their thickness and time (slopes - time varying predictors). Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense to me for the lmer model where the volume is added up across all regions! We're getting the hang of this. 

Comment: I think the same type of model will make sense for each region at a time.

Comment: Make sure you subset your data correctly for each region: data = subset(yourdata, region == "k")  for region k, where k will in turns be 1, 2, ..., 148.

Comment: Awesome! This has been a huge learning experience for me! For the model with all the regions a positive estimate at time2 means increased volume at time 2?

Comment: Yes, increased volume at time 2 (on average across all subjects represented by the ones in your study) relative to time 1, controlling for covariation of volume with thickness.

Comment: Just make sure to code your Time factor such that its reference level is T1 (timepoint 1).

Comment: For your last comment. How can verify this ? I sssumed that became time is coded as time1 = 1 time2=2, r would out time1 as reference

Comment: Just use the function levels() on the Time factor - the first level listed by R is treated as the reference level.

Comment: how about the estimate for thickness. what does it indicate?

Comment: You're just controlling for thickness, so technically speaking you don't really need to worry about its interpretation. But if it is positive, say, it indicates that both volume and thickness tend to go up (or perhaps down) over time on average across individuals.

Comment: One last question... I promise.. What does the intercept indicate in the all_regions <- **lmerTest::lmer(volume~ time + thickness + (1+thickness + time|ID), data = DATA))